# How to find COM port for a specific USB devices connected. of C# 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0

I'm trying to get the list of com port name and the device's name connected to it. (eg: I want to automatically find the COM port for a specific USB device of Fastrack modem M1206B series). In the case where it finds multiple possible ports and i want only finds the port depending on what other usb devices are connected. I tried the following where I get only the list of com ports.

```
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
foreach (string port in ports)
{
cboCOM.Items.Add(port);
}
```

But I need get COMPort only finds the port depending on what other usb devices are connected.

Answer (score 0):

USB does not lie on COM ports. However you can find the port name caption like

```
    getPorts("SAMSUNG X7j4j"); // your device name
    void getPorts(string usbDeviceName)
    {
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub");
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (var device in collection)
        {                
            string deviceId = device["DeviceID"].ToString();
            string port = device["Caption"].ToString();
            if (deviceId == usbDeviceName)
                MessageBox.Show("Port for " + usbDeviceName + " is " + port);                
            //MessageBox.Show(deviceId + "\n" + port + "\n" );
        }
    }
```